# Categorizing sentence using dictionary

Tags: python, text, categorization

I am using below function for getting categorizing sentence in themes

```
def theme(x):
    output =[]
    category = ()
    for i in x:
        if 'AC' in i:
            category = 'AC problem'
        elif 'insects' in i:
            category = 'Cleanliness'
        elif 'clean' in i:
            category = 'Cleanliness'
        elif 'food' in i:
            category = 'Food Problem'
        elif 'delay' in i:
            category = 'Train Delayed'
        else:
            category = 'None'
        output.append(category)
    return output
```

I don't want to use repeated if statements for every word in a category. Instead I want the i give a list/dictionary e.g. `Cleanliness = ['Clean', 'Cleaned', 'spoilt', 'dirty']` for getting category 'Cleanliness' against the sentence if it has any of the words in list. How can i do that

Comment: By using a dictionary.

Comment: Hi. Could you provide us with [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? That means example input and expected output. Cheers.

Comment: But the above is already an *inelegant* way to deal with it, since if one write `'AC insects'`, it will yeild only `'AC problem'`, whereas both are applicable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could u please provide the code. how can i use dictionary

Comment: how about using regex, like `re.search("Clean | Cleaned | spoilt | Dirty", in_you_line)`

Comment: @SuryaTej: then you will need to again perform a manual mapping on the output values.

Comment: @LéopoldHoudin e.g. input -   'Railways shd make a point to inspect at least AC coaches', 'please refund the amount of the train Jamshatapdi express which was cancelled on 14th September', 'right now I m travelling into s8 no clean' and output will be categories e.g. cleanliness

Comment: Then the original program will not work either, since you iterate over the characters, not the words. But regardless, classification with a non-symmetrical algorithm is quite bad.

Comment: Okay, then as @Willem Van Onsem pointed out how do you choose whenever there could be different matches?

Comment: @LéopoldHoudin: what if the sentence is `"Due to food waste, we had AC problems"`. As you can see, both `'Food problem'`, and `AC` problems should get matched. But here we only will select `'AC problem'`. But in general this looks like very error prone design. So no, this algorithm *can* not select multiple themes, due to its anti-symmetrical design, which tends to introduce problems later on.

Comment: No no, I completely agree with you. I was actually asking him how he wants to choose :)
He could potentially have either a preferential match (always choose `AC` over `food`) or he could potentially want to collect **all** *tags*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You u r right, I knew this when i was making this code, I am giving preference to a category over other when both words are their. Also, It will help if you can suggest the answer for, if both words are available

Comment: What type of argument does `theme()` expect? In other words, what's `x`? Do you care about word capitalization? Your question is too vague.

Comment: @martineau x is a series of sentences

Comment: What's a sentence? Is it a string, a list, or what? Please don't repeat the problem by defining it in terms of something else which is undefined, like saying it's a list of words. Please [edit] your question and add some sample inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict of sets to structure your words with categories, and then generate a word-to-category lookup dict based on the said structure:

```
categories = {
    'Cleanliness': {'insects', 'clean'},
    'AC Problem': {'AC'},
    'Food Problem': {'food'},
    'Train Delayed': {'delay'}
}
lookup = {word: category for category, words in categories.items() for word in words}
def theme(x):
    return {lookup.get(word, 'None') for word in x}
```

so that `theme(['AC', 'clean', 'insects'])` would return a set of corresponding categories:

```
{'Cleanliness', 'AC Problem'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're asking. I set all the keys to lowercase and converted i to lowercase when checking if you get a match, but with different capitalization, it still counts.

```
def theme(x):
output =[]
category = ()

myDict = {"ac":"AC problem", "insects":"Cleanliness", "clean":"Cleanliness", "food":"Food Problem", "delay":"Train Delayed"} #I reccomend coming up with a more suitable name for your dictionary in your actual program

for i in x:
    if i.lower() in myDict: #Checks to see if i is in the dictionary before trying to print the result; prevents possible Key Errors
        category = (myDict[i.lower()]) #If it is in the dictionary it category will be set to the result of the key

        output.append(category)

    else:
        output.append("None") #If i isn't in the dictionary output will append None instead
return output
```

Here's some examples:

```
>>>print(theme(['Clean', 'Cleaned', 'spoilt', 'dirty']))
['Cleanliness', 'None', 'None', 'None']

>>>print(theme(['Delay', 'Ham', 'Cheese', 'Insects']))
['Train Delayed', 'None', 'None', 'Cleanliness']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out a another way:

```
def theme(x):
output = []
for i in x:
    if set(cleanliness).intersection(i.lower().split()):
        category = 'clean'
    elif set(ac_problem).intersection(i.lower().split()):
        category = 'ac problem'
    else:
        category = 'none'
    output.append(category)
return output
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
def theme(x):
    output = []
    name_dic = {"AC": "AC problem",
                "clean": "Cleanliness",
                "food": "Food Problem"
                }
    for e in x:
        output.append(name_dic.get(e))

    return output
```

Or more exactly like this:

```
def theme(x):
    output = []
    name_list = [
        ("AC", "AC problem"),
        ("clean", "Cleanliness"),
        ("insects", "Cleanliness"),
        ("food", "Food Problem")
    ]
    name_dic = dict(name_list)
    for e in x:
        output.append(name_dic.get(e))

    return output
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will not work, since if `x` is `'cleaning'`, it will not match with any key.